# Mapping nested arrays of objects

Tags: arrays, object, nested

I have two arrays of objects.

The fist one is:

```
const accounts = [
  {
    "id": "dbcaf288-2b39-4b95-8ab3-42202ab15918",
    "nominalCode": "090",
    "name": "Business Current Account",
    "accountLinks": [
      "UUID1",
      "UUID2",
      "UUID3"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "a989e8c6-376c-43f0-8938-397d7831e216",
    "nominalCode": "091",
    "name": "Business Savings Account",
    "accountLinks": [
      "UUID4",
      "UUID5"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "e5d7612c-1671-47b4-b733-5db48363fcd0",
    "nominalCode": "630",
    "name": "Inventory",
    "accountLinks": []
  },
];
```

And the second one:

```
const entities = [
  {
    "id": "UUID1",
    "name": "EUR Account",
  },
  {
    "id": "UUID2",
    "name": "USD Account",
  },
  {
    "id": "UUID3",
    "name": "Administration",
  },
  {
    "id": "UUID4",
    "name": "Office Supplies",
  },
  {
    "id": "UUID6",
    "name": "Vehicles",
  }
];
```

What I'm trying to get is array based on the accounts but with dropdownAccounts property added with its value of array of entities if the entities[i].id === accounts[i].accountLinks[i] or an empty array if the comparison is false.
So the new array would be like:

```
const rows = [
    {
      id: 'dbcaf288-2b39-4b95-8ab3-42202ab15918',
      nominalCode: '090',
      name: 'Business Current Account',
      accountLinks: [
        'UUID1',
        'UUID2',
        'UUID3',
      ],
      dropdownAccounts: [
        {
          id: 'UUID1',
          name: 'EUR Account',
        },
        {
          id: 'UUID2',
          name: 'USD Account',
        },
        {
          id: 'UUID3',
          name: 'Administration',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 'a989e8c6-376c-43f0-8938-397d7831e216',
      nominalCode: '091',
      name: 'Business Savings Account',
      accountLinks: [
        'UUID4',
        'UUID5',
      ],
      dropdownAccounts: [
        {
          id: 'UUID4',
          name: 'Office Supplies',
        },
        {
          id: 'UUID5',
          name: 'Vehicles',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 'e5d7612c-1671-47b4-b733-5db48363fcd0',
      nominalCode: '630',
      name: 'Inventory',
      accountLinks: [],
      dropdownAccounts: [],
    },
  ];
```

My solution is so far:

```
const rows = accounts.map((account) => {
  return {...account, dropdownAccounts: entities.find(item=>item.id === account.code)}
})
```

But unfortunately it gives me `dropdownAccounts: undefined`
which I'm sadly not surprise as I know I'm loosing the logic in entities.find part of my code.

OK, I've worked it out:

```
const rows2 = accounts.map((account) => {
  return {
    ...account,
    dropdownAccounts: []
  };
});

rows2.forEach((row) => {
  row.accountLinks.forEach((link) => {
    entities.forEach((entity) => {
      if(entity.id === link) {
        row.dropdownAccounts.push(entity);
      }
    })
  })
})
```

However, I'm not happy with the code quality.
Any idea how to make it neater? :)